# How to return a variable from a function as a global variable on click

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, return

I would like to return "a=5" variable from the function on click as a global variable and then alert it. Can you please only reply with javascript codes and not jquery. I am trying to understand javascript.

```js
function startBtn() {
  var a = 5;
  return a;
}

document.getElementsByName("submit-button")[0].addEventListener("click", startBtn);

// var test = startBtn(); //Does not work as I want. I want to pass this as a global variable.
// alert(test); //Does not work as I want
```

```html
<input class="submit-btn" type="submit" name="submit-button" value="Start">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Get the value of the function when the user `click` on the button and `alert` inside `clickListener`.

As per your code snippet you are getting the value of the `startBtn` function outside of the click listener and `alerting` it also give `5`, but you need to get the value and alert that value only after the user click on the button not when JS is compiled.

```js
function startBtn() {
  var a = 5;
  return a;
}

document.getElementsByName("submit-button")[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
  var test = startBtn(); 
  alert(test); 
});

var test = startBtn();
alert(test);
```

```html
<input class="submit-btn" type="submit" name="submit-button" value="Start">
```

Comment: Hi decpk thank you, however, I want to return the value to main section of javascript, I believe what you did is you put another function and called startBtn(); from that? Because in your snippet, test is not a global value if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Gingercook updated code. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to alert a from js function just insert the alert function on your startBtn function like this

```js
function startBtn() {
  var a = 5;
  alert(a);
}

document.getElementsByName("submit-button")[0].addEventListener("click", startBtn);

// var test = startBtn(); //Does not work as I want
// alert(test); //Does not work as I want
```

```html
<input class="submit-btn" type="submit" name="submit-button" value="Start">
```

Comment: Thanks but I just wanted to return a value outside the function.